# Make one button peform differnt actions depending on the state of the applicaton?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0

This is my current setup:

I have a WPF app that has a copy button which takes a applications directory and copies it to another directory.  After this is finished, I have another button that launches the app from the new location.  Ideally, I would like to just have 1 button where after the copying is done, the button's text changes to "Launch" and when clicked it would Launch the app.  The user will however need to be able to do a re-copy by clicking the button again, but this time, it should say "Copy".  Is this possible and even worth it?

Comment: Save your state and check it every time the button is pressed, to see how you should proceed. A simple example is Pause/Play. If state is Paused, I play and change state to Playing. If state is Play, I pause and change state to Paused.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest thing would be to store a state in a variable accessible from your code-behind, and have an `if` statement in the button's `OnClick` deciding what to do.

It is probably not worth the trouble, as buttons that change their meaning may be confusing to your end users. I would do two separate buttons, but I would conditionally enable or disable them, based on the state of the application. When copying is the only action that makes sense, the `[Copy]` button would be enabled, and the `[Run]` button would be disabled. When the state changes, so would the enabled/disabled status of these buttons. This would give clean visual cues to the end users of your application, and make your application easier to test automatically with various UI test automation tools.

Comment: This was my thinking. Too much trouble

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely *possible*, but it seems far simpler to have two buttons.  You could just toggle their visibility depending on your current state, so the "Launch" button is visible when you want to be able to Launch, and the "Copy" button visible when you want to copy.

This would keep your commands simpler (each command does one operation).

Comment: I was thinking this as well, not worth it for something so simple.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it would be to use a `RelayCommand` and then have an if statement that calls the appropriate function.  The `RelayCommand` was defined [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx#id0090030).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I have never used this before.

Answer (score 1):

I would create two `CommandViewModels` which should contain a [`Command`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand.aspx) and `Header`. You then could have a property containing such a model and the [`Button.Content`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.content.aspx) would then be bound to the `Header` of the current `CommandViewModel` and the [`Button.Command`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.buttonbase.command%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) would be bound to the `Command`. You then just need to change that property to the other `CommandViewModel`.  (This could even be done from within the first `Command`'s [`Execute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand.execute.aspx).)

Comment: I have never used this before. I will take a look at it.

Comment: @mydogisbox: My main point was that the one should create a model which contains both the label and what happens on click. How the command is implemented is irrelevant, of course i suspect that most people go with a delegate-taking-command (whatever you may call it).

Comment: Oh I see.  Your object is also the `Content`.  I guess I didn't read closely enough the first time.